# Hi, I am new to JSON and I can't figure out how to integrate multiple strings. I need to hide columns and make the text of appearing items bold

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, hide-elements

So this is the code I'm hiding the columns with:

[image]

- And I need the rest of the items to appear in bold type.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are providing formatting to your group headers and would like the standard columns to all use bold type. You can do this by combining your format with a rowclass format and use the `.ms-fontWeight-bold` class to accomplish this. So your format can be adjusted to the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "groupProps": {
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@group.fieldData.displayValue"
    }
  },
  "additionalRowClass": "ms-fontWeight-bold"
}
```

Should look something like this:

[image]